# loguru ModuleNotFoundError when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, loguru

when building EXE with pyinstaller, the resulting exe file doesn't execute and the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'loguru'' is shown.
Running the pythons script works without any issues.

didn't find any solution that worked so far on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution is to use `--hidden-import=loguru` along with the PyInstaller script. It will add modulename as import statement silently. Hooks are better if you want to specify which import needs what additional modules. --hidden-import is simpler as a one-shot or for debugging.